# Continuity of convex functions at point out of domain

Tags: convex-analysis

I have been studying the continuity of a convex function and having a trouble below:

In some books, the authors defined the the continuity of a convex function $f$ even $f$ is not in $\mbox{dom }f$, for example $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \mbox{  if } x>0, f(x) = +\infty \mbox{  if } x\leq 0,$$
is continuous on $\mathbb R$. This way may cause some unusual thought such as if $f$ is continuous at $x$ then $f$ is bounded on a neighborhood of $x$ will no longer be true.

My question is what do we need to define the continuity at points where the value of function is $\pm \infty$ for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(a)=+\infty$, we can say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ *in the extended sense* if for every $M\in\mathbb R$  there is $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

Notice this is not something special to convex functions. It is often convenient to extend the notion of continuity in this way.

A higher level explanation is that the [extended real line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline{\mathbb R}  =  \mathbb R \cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ can be given a topology (and even a metric); then we just use the topological definition of continuity for functions taking values in $\overline{\mathbb R} $.